# How best can I use Raspberry pi and ASIC?

Tags: solo-mining, raspberry-pi

I had an old Raspberry pi with a Bitmain Antminer 2GH USB plugged into it.

I have joined the bitminter pool and so far have 0.00000094 bitcoins.  In other words, I don't expect to get rich.

Researching this question most answers take into account power consumption.

My question is, for this sort of setup that I have with 1 - 4 2GH USB sticks, if I do solo mining, do I have much chance of getting a bitcoin now and then?

Comment: This is a very frequently asked question.  The computation is easy and is explained [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty#How_soon_might_I_expect_to_generate_a_block.3F).  Usually the answer is "no".  In your case, at current difficulty levels and solo mining total of 8 GH/s, you can expect to mine one block every 286 years.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do the math. The average time to find a block, which is worth a reward of at least 25 BTCs (+fees) is the following:

```
avgtime = difficulty * 2^32 / hashrate
```

The current difficulty is 16,818,461,371. Assuming a hash rate of 2GH/s we get in hours:

```
avgtime = 16818461371 * 2^32 / (2*10^9) / 60 / 60
```

That's about 10032602 hours or 418025 days. To mine solo successfully, you need much, much more hashing power.